# Labeling plotted date with matplotlib and Axes3D

Tags: python, matplotlib

How do I add naming to my Axes3D plot like in the image on top? My image is below:

[image: Axes3D]

Here is my code:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(X_train['width'], X_train['height'], X_train['color_score'], c=y_train, marker='o', s=100)
ax.set_xlabel('width')
ax.set_ylabel('height')
ax.set_zlabel('color_score')
plt.show()
```

What do I have to add to make my bottom graph have names line the top one?
Matplotlib is a bit confusing for a newbie, so showing what line of code with what format would be super helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think `ax.text()` is doing what you want. See [here](https://matplotlib.org/2.1.1/gallery/mplot3d/text3d.html) for a couple of examples.

To robustly infer a good (easy-to-read) placement for the text, given the data, can be challenging. A naive approach could look as follows (didn't test the code):

```
offset = [0, 0, 0.05]
for label in y_train.unique():          
    idx = (y_train==label)
    posX = X['width'][idx].mean() + offset[0]
    posY = X['height'][idx].mean() + offset[1]
    posZ = X['color_score'][idx].mean() + offset[2]
    ax.text(x=posX, y=posY, z=posZ, s=label, zdir=None)
```

In case you are using pandas, the code could look similar to this:

```
X['labels'] = y_train
grouping = X.groupby('labels')
for label, group in grouping:
    center = group[['width', 'height', 'color_score']].mean(axis=0).values
    center += np.asarray(offset)
    ax.text(x=center[0], y=center[1], z=center[2], s=label, zdir=None)
```